# Equals returns all the values in php

Tags: php

In this code I tried to filter some data records from the database using CategoryId but it returns all the category Id's. In my database Category Id's are INT field.

If I echo `$data['Category'];` then it shows all the categoryId's But after the variable comparison it not work.

I mean `if($cat == 1)` is Not working(It's not filter/Show data)

```
 //Some coding here    
       <section id="section-1">
           <div class="vs-content">
                   <div class="widgets-container">
<?php
                mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error()); 
                mysql_select_db("mydb") or die(mysql_error());
                $sql = "SELECT Id,Title,description,Image,Category from News ";
                $query = mysql_query($sql); 
?>
                 <div class="blocks">

 <?php              while($data = mysql_fetch_array($query)){       
                    $cat =     $data['Category'];               
                        if($cat == 1){
?>                      
                        <h3 style="margin-left:   10px;"><?php echo $data['Title'] ?></h3>
                        <div style="width: 50%; margin-right: auto; margin-left: auto;">
                        <img src="images/drink2.jpg" /></div>
                        <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,<?php base64_encode( $data['Image'] )?>"/> 
                        <p style="color: white; font-size: 0.6em;"><?php echo $data['Description'] ?></p>
<?php
                        }
                    }
?>                                  
                </div>
                <div class="blocks">

<?php               while($data = mysql_fetch_array($query)){   
     $cat = $data['Category'];
                    if($cat == 2){
?>                      
                        <h3 style="margin-left: 10px;"><?php echo $data['Title'] ?></h3>
                        <div style="width: 50%; margin-right: auto; margin-left: auto;">
                        <img src="images/drink2.jpg" /></div>
                        <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,<?php base64_encode( $data['Image'] )?>"/>
                        <p style="color: white; font-size: 0.6em;"><?php echo $data['Description'] ?></p>
<?php
                        }
                    }
?>                                  
                </div>
                <div class="blocks">

<?php               while($data = mysql_fetch_array($query)){   
                    $cat = $data['Category'];
                    if($cat == 3){
?>                      
                        <h3 style="margin-left: 10px;"><?php echo $data['Title'] ?></h3>
                        <div style="width: 50%; margin-right: auto; margin-left: auto;">
                        <img src="images/drink2.jpg" /></div>
                        <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,<?php base64_encode( $data['Image'] )?>"/> -->
                        <p style="color: white; font-size: 0.6em;"><?php echo $data['Description'] ?></p>
    <?php
                        }
                    }
       ?>                                   
                </div>                  
          </div>
        </div>

       // Some coding here
```

Comment: Why u have `-->` after 2nd `img` tag ??

Comment: no.thats copy paste mistake.

Comment: Edited with whole code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not filter the records in your database query? This would mean changing your database query as follows:

> $sql = "SELECT Id,Title,description,Image,Category from News WHERE Category = 1";

By taking this approach less data will be returned to PHP and the database call will execute a little faster :)

**Update**: You only really need the three different <div class="blocks"> sections if the contents within them is going to be different. Otherwise you could simply use a single while loop and output the content for all categories in sequence using the data as ordered by the SQL statement.

```
 //Some coding here    
       <section id="section-1">
           <div class="vs-content">
                <div class="widgets-container">
<?php
                mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error()); 
                mysql_select_db("mydb") or die(mysql_error());
                $sql = "SELECT Id,Title,description,Image,Category from News ORDER BY Category";
                $query = mysql_query($sql); 
?>
                    <div class="blocks">

 <?php              while($data = mysql_fetch_array($query)){       
?>                      
                        <h3 style="margin-left:   10px;"><?php echo $data['Title'] ?></h3>
                        <div style="width: 50%; margin-right: auto; margin-left: auto;">
                        <img src="images/drink2.jpg" /></div>
                        <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,<?php base64_encode( $data['Image'] )?>"/> 
                        <p style="color: white; font-size: 0.6em;"><?php echo $data['Description'] ?></p>
<?php
                    }
?>                                  
                    </div>
                </div>
           </div>
    </section>
   // Some coding here
```

If you only need data rendered for a single category then use the WHERE clause in SQL (See first example) to filter the data you require to reduce the SQL call and improve performance.

Answer (score 3):

Why cant you check the condition in select query, Try this,

```
$sql = "SELECT Id,Title,description,Image,Category from News where Category='1'";
```

**Update:**

```
<div class="blocks">            
 <?php      
   while($data = mysql_fetch_array($query)){       
         $cat =  $data['Category'];               
         if($cat == 1){ ?>   
             //Your code             
         <?php  }else if($cat == 2){ ?>                   
             // Your code     
         <?php  }else{ ?>                         

         <?php }?>   
    <?php }?>                     
  </div>
```

Comment: I didnt find any else condition, as in your code, you need only ` Category='1'` values. then in that case you can go with your query directly

Comment: just curious to know, what is the use of checking the condition? what is the difference between the condition inside code?

Comment: In here i need to show only a specific data on specific category

Comment: In your code, i didnt find any difference in the purpose of conditions used. What is the result you ahve expected?

Comment: In the SQL Query I fetched whole data and after that categorize using categoryID

Comment: Please check my updated answer, there is no need of fetching array value 3 times, instead fecth one time and process inside the while loop!

Comment: In the each gategory there's a few records under that.I need to fetch the whole records.that's why i use while 3 times

Comment: No, fetch 1 time and process your all requirements inside that loop itself